# Android sliding app

Tags: android

I want to build android app to learn how to ask in English .i will put 2 sentence s native English and translated one.the user will see these as slides and move between them by sliding his finger.how can build slids in Android studio ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about sliding views then technically it is called in Android as

> flipper

Just go through [this example](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/widget/viewflipper/android-viewflipper-example/?_e_pi_=7%2CPAGE_ID10%2C8208236884).hope this will help you.